# Typescript: is it possible to get type of parameters list of a function?

Tags: typescript

Example:

```
function a(...args: ???type of b() params???) {
  b(...args)
}
```

I want `args` to be type of `b`'s parameters.

If you want to know why would I want that, then it is for code readability/incapsulation. `b` is `import`ed function, and I don't care about its implementation at the level of function `a` declaration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in 3.0 [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) (in RC right now should be out soon)

```
type ArgumentType<T> = T extends (...args: infer U) => any ? U : never;

function a(...args: ArgumentType<typeof b>) {
    function b(...args: any[]) {

    }
}
// More complex examples
function a2(...args: ArgumentType<typeof b>) {
    function b(name: string, value: number) {

    }
}

a2("", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible another way now:

```
function a(...args: Parameters<typeof b>) {
  b(...args);
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20b(str%3A%20string%2C%20num%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20hover%20over%20%22a%22%20below%20to%20see%20its%20signature%20matches%20%22b%22%0D%0Afunction%20a(...args%3A%20Parameters%3Ctypeof%20b%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20b(...args)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)